# crear vector y trasponerlo usando un bucle

Tags: r, bucle-for, bucles

Tengo unas `matrices` del tipo

```
A <- matrix(c(1, 0,  0
              1, 0.1,0
              1, 0.2,0
              1, 0.9 0), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)   #En mis datos reales es una matriz 121*3

B <-  matrix(c(0.06273800 -0.08007714 -0.03178301
              -0.08007714  1.29460000  0.20540957
              -0.03178301  0.20540957  0.23629000), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

**Y debo operar de tal forma que la primera fila de A la pueda multiplicar por B y luego por la traspuesta de la primera fila de A. Luego la segunda fila de A, por B, por a segunda fila de A, y así sucesivamente fila a fila** Ejemplo

```
[1, 0,  0] %*% B * [1
                    0
                    0] = 0.062738 #Este resultado lo quiero almacenar ordenadamente

[1, 0.1, 0] %*% B * [1
                    0.1
                    0] = 0.05966857 Y así sucesivamente y separadamente por cada fila de la matriz.
```

De esta forma, cada operación que esté realizando involucra a la primera fila de A, que tiene una dimensión de 1x3, a B que tiene 3x3, y a la traspuesta de A que tiene 3x1, de tal forma que el resultado es un escalar [1,1].

Y lo quiero escribir en una salida:

result <- data.frame(c(0.062738, 0.05966857, 0.08249114, 0.9672252))

Intenté hacerlo con el siguiente bucle, pero como pueden ver en mis comentarios, hay partes que no funcionan

```
resul <- data.frame()

for(i in seq_len(nrow(A))){        #Compruebo que recorre todas las filas de todas las columnas
     print(combi[,i])
    for(j in seq_len(ncol(A))){
      print(combi[i,j])          #Compruebo que va leyendo la primera fila de las 3 columnas
       #bec = as.vector([i,j])   #Intento crear un vector que me almacene la 1,0,0 y resuelva 
                                  "Operación". No funciona 
       #operacion = bec *%* P * t(bec) 
       result = rbind (result, operacion)
    }
  }
```

Cómo debo hacerlo?

Comment: Edité la pregunta para facilitar el entendimiento de lo que quiero hacer

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas es aplicar por fila un calculo como este:

```
(fila_x %*% B) %*% t(fila_x)
```

Ciertamente el resultado en este caso sería un matriz de 1 x 1, pero tal vez te encontraste con un problema por eso en tu formula indicas la  multiplicación elemento a elemento `*`, y este es un problema causado por un  comportamiento por defecto de R, muchas veces cuestionado, que es la promoción, cuando corresponde, de un objeto más complejo a uno más simple, en este caso, cuando seleccionas una sola fila, por ej: `A[1, ]` obtienes un vector simple y no una matriz, por lo que la multiplicación matricial dejaría de funcionar como tal. Esto se puede corregir mediante el parámetro `drop`:

```
A[1, ]
[1] 1 0 0

A[1, , drop=FALSE]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
 
dim(A[1, ])             # Un vector simple no tiene dimensiones
NULL

dim(A[1, , drop=FALSE]) # una matriz si
[1] 1 3
```

Entendiendo que siendo tal vez este el problema que moviliza tu pregunta, podría sugerirte algunos cambios en tú código:

```
result <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:dim(A)[1]) {
  operacion = (A[i, , drop = FALSE] %*% B) %*% t(A[i, , drop=FALSE])
  result = rbind (result, operacion)
}
result

          V1
1 0.06273800
2 0.05966857
3 0.08249114
4 0.96722515
```

Simplemente vamos iterando por fila y aplicamos la formula pero esta vez asegurándonos que siempre trabajemos con matrices.

También puedes simplificar todo en una sola línea y evitas el potencial problema de usar `rbind` dentro de un ciclo que tiene una penalidad importante en performance:

```
sapply(1:dim(A)[1], 
       FUN = function(i){(A[i, , drop = FALSE] %*% B) %*% t(A[i, , drop=FALSE])})

[1] 0.06273800 0.05966857 0.08249114 0.96722515
```

Comment: Gracias Patricio, es muy útil lo que propones. Sin embargo, creo que no plantee mi pregunta con suficiente claridad. La edité a ver si ahora se entiende mejor

Comment: Hola @Caro, creo que entiendo, me confundió que en tú código la segunda multiplicación no sea matricial.